# Allow only HTTPS URL in input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, trumbowyg

I am using [Trumbowyg](https://alex-d.github.io/Trumbowyg/), a WYSIWYG JavaScript editor which allows rendering images by pasting a URL.

So you paste the URL in the field and then click the `Confirm` button and then it appends the image in the editor ([you can test it out here](https://alex-d.github.io/Trumbowyg/))

I want to prevent adding images that are not HTTPS. So if someone inserts a URL that is not HTTPS, I want to prevent appending the image when they click `Confirm`.

This is the function for the image URL ([from the docs](https://github.com/Alex-D/Trumbowyg/blob/develop/src/trumbowyg.js#L1305)):

```
insertImage: function () {
            var t = this;
            t.saveRange();

            var options = {
                url: {
                    label: 'URL',
                    required: true
                },
                alt: {
                    label: t.lang.description,
                    value: t.getRangeText()
                }
            };

            if (t.o.imageWidthModalEdit) {
                options.width = {};
            }

            t.openModalInsert(t.lang.insertImage, options, function (v) { // v are values
                t.execCmd('insertImage', v.url);
                var $img = $('img[src="' + v.url + '"]:not([alt])', t.$box);
                $img.attr('alt', v.alt);

                if (t.o.imageWidthModalEdit) {
                    $img.attr({
                        width: v.width
                    });
                }

                t.syncCode();
                t.$c.trigger('tbwchange');

                return true;
            });
        }
```

Any idea how I can amend this function to only allow HTTPS inputs?

Comment: `var url = v.url; if(!url.match(/^https:\/\//)){ return false; }`. Put it right above `t.execCmd('insertImage', v.url);`

Comment: Works perfect...thankyou! Is there any way a user can bypass this somehow as it is only a front-end function? Or is it secure?

Comment: Anything client side is insecure! It's why should _always_ verify user provided data server side. Regex is language independent though. So just check how regex works on whatever language is used server side and use the same pattern `/^https:\/\//`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good solution for this problem would be to use [Regular Expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression), or short: Regex.

Regex allowes you to verify if a string actually contains the data you're expecting. A downside of regex though is that it's CPU intensive. That's why regex should only be used if no other function is available to do the job. As it happens, there's another function available for this: [substr()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr).

Therefor the better solution would be:

```
var url = v.url;

if(!url.substr(0,7) === 'https://'){
    return false;
}
```

Though learning regex is definitely helpfull in the long run. A website that will help you a lot with this is https://regex101.com/. You'll eventually run into situations where other solutions simply aren't available. Therefor testing with regex is a good way to learn. Using regex, the solution would be:

```
var url = v.url;

if(!url.match(/^https:\/\//)){
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either use regular expression to check for the presence of 'https' in the url like url.match(/^https/) or you can use url.startsWith('https') to find if a url starts with https or not.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a regular expression to check this

```
var url = v.url;
```

then use the match function

```
url.match(/^https:\/\//);
```

Beware of using `startsWith('https')` to check this, as `startsWith()` is not supported in all browsers